# Typescript how to extend Record

Tags: typescript, types

I often want to extend the type `Record` in my interface to define object with predefined key and optional (without knowing the name)

For example

```js
interface Person extends Record<string, string>{
 phonenumber: number,
 name: string
}
```

However I got this error
`Property 'phonenumber' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string'`

So I do not know how to define my interface to get `phonenumber` as a number type but all other possible field as string type

Comment: `Record<string, string>` is functionally equivalent here as extending an interface with `{ [s: string]: string }` This means all indexing operation should return `string`, but if you have a property `phonenumber: number` , indexing with `phonenumber` will return `number`, so the indexing operation would be unreliable .

Answer (score 0):

As Titian Cernicova-Dragomir commented on your initial question, the following typescript code will **error**.

```
interface IPhone {
  phonenumber: number, // <= error
  [s:string]: string,
}
```

Can you get away with using a generic `interface` ?,
e.g.

```
interface IStringTMap<T> { [key: string]: T; }
interface IStringStringMap extends IStringTMap<string> { }
interface IStringNumberMap extends IStringTMap<number> { }
```

Alternatively, you could use the following interface, but I suspect it will not be all that helpful, as it sacrifices the type safety as you will need to check the type of each property.

```
interface IPhone {
  phonenumber: number, // <= no more error
  [s: string]: string | number
}
```

Comment: You are right, it does not solve my problem because I wanted to have for all unknwon property type is string only, for known property type is what we want (boolean, number...).
I am not sure I can achieve this with your solutions